# GetAsyncKeyState to repeat same key

Tags: wpf, vb.net

```
Imports InputManager
'Using inputmanager to send keys

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    hotkeyx = GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.X)
                If hotkeyX < 0 Then
            Keyboard.KeyUp(Keys.X)
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5)
            Keyboard.KeyDown(Keys.X)
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5)
    End If
    'Timer1 interval is 10 ms
```

1. The problem is if I do this, when I press and hold X for about 5 seconds then
   it will just repeat X indefinitely even if I release the X key.
2. I only want X repeated when I hold down X key then I want it to stop when I release it.

Help me please.

If I add, Keyboard.KeyUp(Keys.X) following Keyboard.KeyDown(Keys.X) then it will not repeat it when I release the key but then the key will be repeated much slower and GetAsyncKeyState will take longer to detect the key press so I can't do that. –  user1785594 2 hours ago

Also If I increase Timer1 interval to 50 ms, then async repeat problem will become less frequently but it still does that and I don't think that's the right way to do it.

```
Dim cntNo As Int32 = 0

    Private Sub CheckKey(ByVal key As Integer)
            Dim state = GetAsyncKeyState(key)
            If state < 0 Then
                prevState(key) = True
                Keyboard.KeyUp(CType(key, Keys))
'keyup to simulate X keyUp for target program
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5)
'5ms interval is required for me

                Keyboard.KeyDown(CType(key, Keys))
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5)
'Above code is much better than previous one but it does unintended async repeat sometimes
                cntNo = cntNo + 1
                If cntNo > 10 Then
                    Keyboard.KeyUp(CType(key, Keys))
                    cntNo = 0
                End If
'If it's repeated for 10 times then send keyUP to end it

            ElseIf prevState(key) Then
                prevState(key) = False
                Keyboard.KeyUp(CType(key, Keys))
            End If
        End Sub

     Private Sub Timer4_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer4.Tick
                      CheckKey(Keys.X)
               End Sub
```

'-Thanks to Hans Passant, I made a working code but I think I used improper way to do this though.
Since program require keyUP to simulate X key press, it will have the same problem although not as often as before, I don't know how to solve it so I just added key up for every 10 rounds. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Please, delete this comments and include the information in the question (you can edit it as much as you wish).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code snippet is strange, it generates a KeyUp notification when the key is down.  You can normally rely on the value returned by GetAsyncKeyState() to detect a key-up state, bit #0 will be set if the key was previously down.  But that's pretty unlikely to work correctly when you also have a Timer ticking, clearly your code has a dispatcher loop.

So you need to keep track of the previous value to detect the key-up state:

```
Private prevState(255) As Boolean
```

Your timer Tick event handler now just need to update this array and generate the notification as desired.  Making it as generic as possible:

```
Private Sub CheckKey(key As Integer)
    Dim state = GetAsyncKeyState(key)
    If state < 0 Then
        prevState(key) = True
        Keyboard.KeyDown(CType(key, Keys))
    ElseIf prevState(key) Then
        prevState(key) = False
        Keyboard.KeyUp(CType(key, Keys))
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    CheckKey(Keys.X)
End Sub

Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32.dll" (key As Integer) As Short
```

Do beware of the failure modes of code like this.  If the key is held down for a very short time, less than the timer's Interval, then you'll completely miss it.  You are much better off using the operating system's provided KeyUp/Down events, you can never miss those.  Just use that same array to generate the events.  And you cannot rely on a 10 msec timer interval, the default is 15.625 msec.